# Combining two independent columns based on criteria of one (matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix, lookup, zero

I have a column of values which outputs like the following:

```
d =

 1
 1
 3
 1
 1
 2
 1
```

I am looking to combine the integers that are > 0 to the following:

```
e =

 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
10
```

So for instance the first value is 1 so it would only be assigned to one value in e (the first). I am looking to have an unique identifier for each separate value to output this:

```
e =

 1   1
 2   2
 3   3
 4   3
 5   3
 6   4
 7   5
 8   6
 9   6
10   7
```

Comment: See [**here**](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/274540).

Answer (score 0):

here is a one-liner using `bsxfun`

```
e = [e 1+sum(bsxfun(@gt, 1:sum(d),cumsum(d))).'];
```